# Intersection and union

Tags: linear-algebra

$(1,2)$ intersection $(2,3)=\{2\}$

$(1,2)$ intersection $[2,3]=\{2\}$

$\{1,2\}$ intersection $[1,2]=[1,2]$

$\{1,2\}$ union $[1,2]=[1,2]$

$\{1,2\}$ intersection  $(1,3)$ intersection $[1,3)=(1,3)$

$\{1,2\}$ union $(1,3)$ union $[1,3)=(1,3)$

Is my answer correct?  I find my self confused when I have sets $\{a,b\}$ and intervals like $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ to find intersection and union of them.

Comment: $\{ a, b\}$ are points, $(a, b)$ is the collection of all real numbers $a < x < b$, and $[a, b]$ is the collection of all real numbers $a \leq x \leq b$.

Comment: 1) is wrong.  2) is wrong.  3) is wrong.  4) is right (a fluke; I imagine). 5 is wrong.  6 is wrong.  Go back and review.  You don't understand this at all.  {a,b} is the set of specific points.  (a,b) are all points that are between a and b but not including a and b.  [a,b] are all points between and a and b.  Unions is all points in a all sets combined.   Intersection is points that are in every one of the sets.  So every answer you gave (but one) were completely wrong.

Comment: thank you, I know that but I do not know how to get correct answer any help

Comment: Well what numbers, if any do $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ have in common?  What numbers if any do $(1,2)$ and $[2,3]$, if any, have in common? What numbers do {1,2} and [1,2], if any, have in common? What do you get if you combine the number {1,2} with the numbers in [1,2]? What numbers, if any, do {1,2}, (1,3) and [1,3) have in common? What do you get if you combine {1,2} with (1,3) with [1,3)?

Comment: Are there any number that are both larger than 1 and less than 2, and also larger than 2 and less than 3?

Comment: do you mean the answer of part 1 is phi (empty)

Comment: the answer of 3 is {1,2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Q: $x\in (1,2)\implies x<2.$

$x\in (2,3)\implies x>2.$

Therefore $x\in (1,2)\cap (2,3)\implies (x\in (1,2)$ AND $x\in (2,3))\implies (x<2$ AND $x>2).$  No $x$ exists that is both $<2$ and $>2$. So no $x$ belongs to $(1,2)\cap (2,3).$

Second Q: $x\in (1,2)\implies x<2.$

$x\in [2,3]\implies x\geq 2. $

Therefore $x\in (1,2)\cap [2,3]\implies (x\in (1,2)$ AND $x\in [2,3])\implies (x<2$  AND $x\geq 2.)$ No $x$ exists that is both $<2$ and $\geq 2$. So no $x$ belongs to $(1,2)\cap [2,3].$

Third Q: $$x\in \{1,2\}\cap [1,2]\iff (x\in \{1,2\} \text { AND } x\in [1,2])\iff$$ $$\iff (\;(x=1 \text { OR } x=2)\; \text { AND } (\;1\leq x\leq 2\;)\;)\iff$$ $$\iff (x=1 \text { OR } x=2).$$ So $\{1,2\}\cap [1,2]=\{1,2\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Draw out the intervals on aligned number lines. If one side is a square bracket, make the dot at that end solid, meaning that the endpoint is included in the interval. If it's a parenthesis, make the dot open, meaning that it's not included in the interval.

Here's the first one:
[image: intersection]

The only possible overlap point is at $2$, and it's not included in either set. So, the intersection is the empty set: $\{\}$.

Can you do the others?

Comment: ok.I will show you now

Comment: 1 is empty, 2 is (1,2) ,3 is {1,2} ,4 is [1,2] ,5 is {1,2} , 6 is [1,3)